# Pass the label that was clicked to its clicked method. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, events, event-handling

So I have a 2D array of labels:

```
Label[][] _mainAreaLabels = new Label [MAX_COLUMNS_OF_CARDS][];
```

And I can add assign a method to be called when they are clicked:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= _mainAreaLabels.Length - 1 ; i++) //for each column
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= _mainAreaLabels[i].Length - 1; j++ )
    {
        _mainAreaLabels[i][j].Click += ActiveLabelsClicked;
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to actually pass the label that was clicked (or just the index of the label that was clicked - either is fine) to the ActiveLabelsClicked method. In the ActiveLabelsClicked method I want to update a separate label that contains the text of the label in the array that was clicked, which I can't do without passing ActiveLabelsClicked some information about which label in the array  **was**  clicked!

Comment: The event handler usually has a `sender` argument, you could use that.

Comment: Are we talking about WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET ?

Comment: WinForms (extra chars)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your event handler looks like this:

```
void ActiveLabelsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
   // do stuff with the 'sender' object
}
```

The `sender` object will contain the object you clicked on.

Comment: +1, but the event handler cannot really look like anything else ;-)

Comment: Can I change the type of sender to a Label?

Comment: @Jon just making sure ;)

Comment: @user1091236 you are better of creating a local variable and cast the sender to a label in that

Comment: `var label = (Label)sender;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of the Tag property:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= _mainAreaLabels.Length - 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= _mainAreaLabels[i].Length - 1; j++) {
    _mainAreaLabels[i][j].Tag = new int[] { i, j };
    _mainAreaLabels[i][j].Click += ActiveLabelsClicked;
  }
}

void ActiveLabelsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var label = (Label)sender;
  var tag = (int[])label.Tag;
  int column = tag[0];
  int row = tag[1];
}
```